# Running bat on a UNC Path throws Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a website that is meant to run a bat file specified by an admin on the machine that is running the site. The bat files exist on a UNC path, so the bat file would be located in `\\domain\path\to\bat\file.bat` and my C# code would run that file. When running on a localhost, the bat file runs correctly, however, when publishing to a local domain, the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method returns an exception with the message "The system cannot find the file specified". The `output` object is a simple dictionary that is sent to a jquery AJAX call

```
if(File.Exists(BatPath)) {
     try
     {
         ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(BatPath);
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);
         output["text"] = "Tests started.";
         output["success"] = "yes";
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         output["text"] = e.Message;
         output["success"] = "no";
     }
 }
 else
 {
     output["text"] = "The file " + BatPath + " could not be found.";
     output["success"] = "no";
 }
```

At first glance, I feel that if the file doesn't exist, the `output["text"]` should be that the file could not be found, but that is not the case. What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: `\domain` is not enough. Should be `\\domain` I'd say

Comment: @ThomasWeller you're right, that was a typo in the post. Fixing that right now. In the code, the unc path starts with `\\domain`

Comment: A safe bet would be to explicitly specify a non-UNC path working directory for the process and also execute the process `cmd.exe` with arguments `/k "BATCH_FILE_UNC_PATH"`. Also verify that you don't have a problem with a backslash being not ecaped properly. Don't forget double quoting the UNC Path